# ld resolve multiple definition manually

Tags: c, ld

I have a unit test file that is a part of a large framework. Some of the framework classes I'm using in the tests are mocked up versions to return the values I need for testing. That is I redefined some of the framework classes in my own c source files.

Is there a way to force ld on Linux to use my own framework classes objects, other than removing the framework libraries from the linker line? I can't really remove the libraries because I'm still using some of the framework objects without modifications.

This is the link error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/char_traits.h:250:
>   multiple definition of `MyClass::MyClass'
>   build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/tests/tests/my_ut.o:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/exception:62:
>   first defined here ../frameworklib.a(MyClass.o): In function`
>   MyClass':

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that my version of ld exits with an error in case of multiple definitions, regardless of the order of the objects on the command line. The [-z muldefs](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/ld_3.html) changes this behaviour.

> ld --version
>   GNU ld version 2.20.51.0.2-5.20.el6 20091009
>   Copyright 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: That sounds like a dangerous option. You'd better make sure that the right symbols are used. Are both your frameworks object (`.o`) files or are there libraries as well (`.a`)? In my experience libraries don't lead to multiple definitions. Object files are always included, so then multiple definitions make sense.

Comment: The error message that I added to the question clearly states that the conflicting definition comes from an archive library. The unit test objects are just objects. You mentioned in your answer to place either the "object or the library" file defining the unit test versions before the framework library.

Comment: I've added a further analysis, but it is stretching on my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Place the object or library file containing your own framework classes before the library of the large framework on the command line of `ld`, but after the object/library files using them. If you intend your own framework classes to be used by the large framework (as well), then you are out of luck.

The error message shows that the first resolution of the symbol comes from `frameworklib.a` and the redefinition occurs in `my_ut.o`. This suggests that `frameworklib.a` occurs before `my_ut.o` on the command-line of `ld`. It is however a complicating factor that the definitions seem to also come from header files (C++). I'm not an expert on C++ but it is conceivable that both definitions are actually included in the application through the use of the different include files at different places. If you want to overrule the class definitions you probably should make sure that all occurrences of the class are overruled. If that is the case I would advice you to take some time and discussion with colleagues to come up with a good design for unit testing.

Comment: I did change the order as you described but I get the same linker error message.